# TeX capacity exceeded using pgfplots with/without externalization when compiling with PDFLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, externalize

I have very big issues in externalizing and generella produce plot with latex.

I'm compiling with PDFLatex and the compiler is texmaker. I'm compiling my thesis that consists in different chapters and some plots. i already red all the topics about this problem but i can't get a solution.

the problem are:

- first, latex refuse to externalize picture, so i added `--enable-write18` in the library with `\usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize`.
- after that, some plot were drawn, but memory exceed problem come along;
- i add the line `--extra-mem-bot=100000000` (now it's removed) but after i reach 21000000000 it can compile no more;

At this moment the lines `\usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize` are commented because the compiler totally stopped to work even with them on and only loaded the picture already created, even i modify them.

what would i do to solve the problem?

Comment: it's easier to debug if you don't use externalise simply make a latex document for each of your larger tikz images and check they work. If they work you are done (you can simply include the pdf into your main document) if they don't you have isolated to just a tikzpicture without the extra code for your thesis and you could ask a specific question here about whatever error is raised

Comment: already did this: chapters are included in the main tex file and in each chapter a .tex file containing three plots is loaded.

Comment: i just want to compile all the document together with no need of loading the plot pictures.

Comment: well if you run out of memory what you want and what tex can do may not be the same thing. But your descreption of what you dis and my suggestion do not seem to match. Can you run each tikzpicture as a separate document that just has one tikzpicture and nothing else, if you already run out of memory doing that then the issue is in the tikz not in assembling teh thesis document.

Comment: thank you, for the support. in this moment i reactivate the externalize part adding 

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,shell escape=-enable-write18]

in the main. i ran out of memory again with the messagge 
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]

displayed.

so you're basically telling me to create a tex document for each plot and try to run it separately? the structure of this polt consists in 

\begin{figure}

Comment: the structure of this plot consists in 

\begin{figure}
\begin {subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
(graph informations)
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicure}
\end{subfigure}
\begin {subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
(graph informations)
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicure}
\end{subfigure}
\begin {subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
(graph informations)
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

Comment: it just stop at the end of the first subfiigure

Comment: forget figures just \documenclass{article}\usepackage{tikz, or pgfplots or whatever}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{documen}`